# Substitution in two coupled Ito SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we have the set of simple coupled stochastic differential equations (SDEs) in Ito form
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}X & =\left\{ c_{x}X+c_{xz}Z\right\} \text{d}t+\left\{ c_{z}Z\right\} \mathrm{d}W\left(t\right)\,,\\
\mathrm{d}Z & =\left\{ -c_{xz}X\right\} \mathrm{d}t+\left\{ c_{z}\left(1-Z^{2}\right)\right\} \mathrm{d}W\left(t\right) \,,
\end{align*}
where $X$ and $Z$ are real variables of the time, $t$. Could we eliminate $X$ from the description and write a single equation for the Z dynamics? I suppose it would have to be a second-order-in-time equation. I am not sure how to proceed, any pointers in the right direction, such as a chapter of textbook or your approach to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just checking: Are the two Wiener processes really the same, i.e., it doesn’t need to be $\mathrm{d} W_1(t)$ in the first and $\mathrm{d} W_2(t)$ in the second equation?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. They are indeed the same.